# return latest version of a drupal node

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-6

I'm writing a drupal module, and I need to write a query that returns particular rows of one of my content_type tables. My query so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pb.*, f.filepath FROM {content_type_promo_box} pb LEFT JOIN {files} f ON pb.field_promo_image_fid = f.fid
```

I realized as I was working that the table not only contains each cck field of this content type, it also contains multiple **versions** for each field. How do I limit my query to the rows that only contain values for the **current** versions of the nodes?

UPDATE: I need to clarify my question a little. I've been down the views path already, and I did think about using node_load (thanks for the answer, though, Jeremy!). Really, my question is more about how to write an appropriate SQL statement than it is about drupal specifically. I only want to return rows that contain the latest versions (vid is the greatest) for any particular node (nid). So here's an example:

```
-------------
| nid | vid |
-------------
| 45  |  3  |
| 23  |  5  |
| 45  |  9  |
| 23  |  12 |
| 45  |  36 |
| 33  |  44 |
| 33  |  78 |
-------------
```

My query should return the following:

```
-------------
| nid | vid |
-------------
| 23  |  12 |
| 45  |  36 |
| 33  |  78 |
-------------
```

Make sense? Thanks!

Comment: What did you mean, revisioned nodes or multiple-valued field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `(nid, vid)` combination is unqiue:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  nid, MAX(vid) AS mvid
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                nid
        ) q
JOIN    mytable m
ON      (m.nid, m.vid) = (q.nid, q.mvid)
```

Comment: I got an error until I changed "q.vid" to "q.mvid" in the last line. Then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot simply assume that MAX(vid) will return the current revision. The point of having revisions is that you can revert to a previous version, right? Instead of searching for the highest version id, you should retrieve the current vid for your nid from the node table.

Having said this, I tend to agree most with the answer of Jeremy French, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054629/return-latest-version-of-a-drupal-node/2055856#2055856.

Comment: Doesn't reverting to a previous revision create a new revision id, though?

Comment: Some modules don't publish the newest revision until it is approved.  In such a case, the highest version is not the current version.

Comment: Since version ids are unique across all content and stored in the nodes table, a subquery is not needed.  Check my answer for query a query that should avoid any MAX() problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054629/return-latest-version-of-a-drupal-node/2121582#2121582

Answer (score 4):

The node table stores the current version of the node, and revision ids are unique across all content.  This makes for a pretty simple query:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    
    {mytable} AS m
JOIN {node} AS n
ON m.vid = n.vid
```

If there is no content in `{mytable}` for the node, it will not be returned by the query; change to a `RIGHT JOIN` to return all nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You may be better off using [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_load/6) to get the load object rather than trying to write a query yourself.

Or even use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to do what you need.

The reason for doing this over writing a query for yourself is that Drupal and it's modules sit together as a framework. Most of the time you will want to use that framework to do what you want rather than side stepping it to write your own query. In future if you upgrade Drupal or a module node_load() will still work but your code may not.